# How to determine length of audio file associated with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

Does anyone know how to get attributes from a file associated with an instance of AVAudioPlayer..specifically I am looking how to determine the length of a WAV file.

Answer (score 17):

If you want the length in seconds, `audioPlayer.duration` should do it.